# What was the "New Human" movement in the ST:TMP novel?

Tags: star-trek

In the novelization of ST:TMP, I remember reading about CPT. Decker having been brought up in the "New Human" movement as a boy, introduced to it by his mother.

For the life of me, I can't recall what that movement was supposed to be about.

Does anyone have any information on that?

Answer (score 2):

#### From the [Star Trek, The Motion Picture Novel](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Star_Trek:_The_Motion_Picture_(novel)) page on Memory Alpha:

> New Humans
> In the early-23rd century, society was evolving to a point where large numbers of "New Humans", telepathically linked as a group mind, represented a sizable portion of Human society. Although more intelligent than normal humans, these people proved incapable of deep space exploration, lacking the ability to bear encounters with more advanced beings than themselves - for all their intelligence, aloofness was a hindrance to them.

- In the novelization, Admiral Kirk explains in the forward that the New Humans were more highly evolved breed of Humanity capable of finding rewards in group consciousness. (Page 5)
- It was determined, however, they were less suited to space travel because after the Vulcans helped with a study of early Federation missions, it would seem New Humans among the crews of those early ships were prone to mutiny, crew defections and ship disappearances.
- The Vulcan research indicated they were "seduced by the alien life forms, higher philosophies, aspirations and consciousness levels being encountered." (Page 6)
- Kirk notes he and his class were the first group selected by Starfleet "on the basis of somewhat more limited intellectual agility." (Page 6)
- There was also some indication that the New Human Movement was critical of StarFleet's mission, aims and costs to maintain. (Page 40)

Comment: Thaddeus... all over that! Thank you, good sir. : )